# Android studio warning that Android API 29 and 33 are missing or currupt

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, android-api-levels

I am getting the following 2 warnings in Android Studio. It doesn't prevent me from building and running my flutter app.

How can I fix this? If they are missing, how do I install them? And if they are corrupt, how do I remove/uninstall them and then set them up?

[image: android studio API warnings]

Comment: Go to menu "Tools" >>>> "SDK Manager"

Comment: That's what I used originally to install API's 28 thru to 34. I started getting this warning straight away. I have since unticked API level 29, 33, 33-ext4 and 33-ext5. I clicked Ok to remove them and then after a Windows reboot, I re-ticked them only to receive the same warnings again.

Comment: Then try to "Configure" and set the correct path by hand.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, its driving me a little insane, the more I mess around with configure, the more damage it does to debug the warning, theres no ignore button either so it just stays up top. hopefully google will patch it up in a few days

Comment: I'm starting to think this is actually coming from some problem in the project itself (some setting in the project), as I have another flutter project that doesn't display these warnings when it is loaded. Can anyone think of a setting in a project file that could cause these warnings?